# Grid Items are changing when scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, android-custom-view, baseadapter

Hi I am working with custom GridView.

The GridView placed in the following xml/layout file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/music_home_ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/music_home_root_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/music_home_promo_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/music_home_promo_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/music_home_promo_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.raaga.home.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/music_home_page_indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/music_home_grid_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/music_home_promo_frame"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The GridView contains the following views

**music_grid_item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/music_grid_image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/new_releases" 

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/music_grid_category_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/music_grid_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
        android:text="New Releases"
        android:textColor="@color/text_white"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have used the custom adapter class and followed [this link](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

**MusicCategoryAdapter.java**

```
    public class MusicCategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<Integer> categoryImageList;
    ArrayList<String> categoryNameList;
    Context mContext;

    public MusicCategoryAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Integer> categoryImageList, ArrayList<String> categoryNameList) {

        this.mContext= mContext;
        this.categoryImageList = categoryImageList;
        this.categoryNameList = categoryNameList;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        //send the list length
        return categoryImageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        GridHolder holder;
         View grid = convertView;
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              if (convertView == null) {
                grid = new View(mContext);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_grid_item, null);
                holder = new GridHolder();
            holder.categoryTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.music_grid_category_name);
            holder.categoryImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.music_grid_image);
            holder.categoryTitle.setText(categoryNameList.get(position));
            holder.categoryImage.setImageResource(categoryImageList.get(position));
                convertView.setTag(holder);
              } else {
                holder = (GridHolder) convertView.getTag();
              }
          return convertView;

    }

    public class GridHolder{
        ImageView categoryImage;
        TextView categoryTitle;
    }
}
```

I am facing the problem that the items are repeating by changing the position when scrolling.

Could anyone help on this problem? What mistake I did in this?

Answer (score 0):

Put the scrollview at the starting of relative layout and end the tag in the end of the relative layout.
This would make your entire layout scrollable and you will overcome the problem.

Comment: kumar same result after changes made